# how to disable width: 100%; and box-sizing: border-box;

Tags: css

I have submit button in wrapper div. I have global settings for all this situations where input is in wrapper like that.

I want just for one to be in center of wrapper, but property `width:100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` is on full width so my `text-align: center;` property will not work. I want to disable full width to margin button to center of wrapper.

### Question:

How to disable `width: 100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` with CSS?

*Therefore I can center input to center.*

### HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperInput">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#wrapper .wrapperInput input {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with:

```
#wrapper .wrapperInput input {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
     box-sizing: content-box;
}
```